# Is not a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a big problem, I can't execute my jQuery code correctly.

I edited the post to show the html...

```
<select id="corrector" name="availability" value="" onchange="escorrecto();" >
    <option value="correcto"></option>
    <option value="incorrecto"></option>
    <option value="nodefinido"></option>
</select>
```

and the jQuery code...

```
function escorrecto() 
{
    switch ($('corrector').value) 
    {
        case 'correcto':
            alert($('corrector').value)
        break;
        case 'incorrecto':
            alert($('corrector').value)
        break;

        case 'nodefinido':
            alert($('corrector').value)
            $("#campo").prop("disabled",true); 
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Show the rest of it.  What have you tried?  What is this supposed to do?  Show the HTML and maybe a jsFiddle demo.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('campo').value
```

is supposed to be

`$('.campo').val()` If Class  **OR**  `$('#campo').val()` if id

**.value** is the `native javascript method`

**.val()** is a `jQuery method`

If you want to use the `.value` then this should work

```
$('#campo')[0].value;
```

Also In `$("otro").attr("disabled","disabled");`

prefer to use `.prop()`  instead of `.attr()`

```
$("#otro").prop("disabled",true);
```

**Check Code**

```
<select id="corrector" name="availability" value="" onchange="escorrecto();" >
    <option value="correcto">Correcto</option>
    <option value="incorrecto">Incorrecto</option>
    <option value="nodefinido">Nodefinido</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="campo" value="Submit" />
<script>
    function escorrecto() 
{
    var val = $('#corrector')[0].value
    switch (val) 
    {
        case 'correcto':
            alert(val)
        break;
        case 'incorrecto':
            alert(val)
        break;

        case 'nodefinido':
            alert(val)
            $("#campo").prop("disabled",true); 
        break;
    }
}
</script>
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/tq2MA/)**
​

Comment: No, is a correct alert message this isn´t the problem.

Comment: @AdrianSeg, then you need to better explain your problem, because those are still real problems with your code.

Comment: Can you show your HTML structure??